# Git Config issue

Tags: macos, git, github, terminal, repository

I think I may have misconfigured my config file for Git's command-line tools.

Whenever I am trying to install something using the git repository URL, I get following error:

```
fatal: '.insteadofgithub.com/angular/bower-angular.git' does not appear to be a git repository
```

I played with the URL for replacing `git://` with `http://`, but, unfortunately, it's not reverting back.

Is there a command line to re-configure my URLs?

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Can you post your .gitconfig content? Probably a wrong `insteadOf` entry.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `insteadOf` was misused. If you would like to use `https://` instead of `git://`, or something else, you can use:

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

This will add the following content, in your `${HOME}/.gitconfig` file:

```
[url "https://"]   
    insteadOf = git://
```